# Matrix equation for $SL(4,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: matrices

Suppose $E=\{X\in M_4(\mathbb{C}): X^T=-X\}$ and that there exists $a\in SL(4,\mathbb{C})$ such that for all $X\in E$
$$
aXa^T=X
$$
I want to show that it follows that $a=\pm I$. This can be done by finding a basis for $E$ and working with matrix multiplication directly, but this is not an elegant argument. Is there perhaps a better one? Is it possible to show that $a\in Z(SL(4,\mathbb{C}))$ maybe?

Comment: If you take $X$ to be the zero matrix then $X \in E$ and $a$ can be anything you want.

Comment: @mtiano, the equality needs to hold for all $X\in E$, not just for $X=0$.

Comment: @JimmyR: In this case, you have to change the order of the quantifiers: There exists $a$, such that for all $E$...

Comment: @gerw, sure, done it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $X$ of the form $vw^T - wv^T$, where $u,v$ are vectors.

Take $v$ as a right singular vector of $A$ such that $Av=su$. Then
\begin{align*}
&A(vw^T - wv^T)A^T = vw^T - wv^T\quad \forall w\in\mathbb{C}^n\\
\Rightarrow&su(Aw)^T - s(Aw)u^T = vw^T - wv^T\quad \forall w\in\mathbb{C}^n.
\end{align*}
As $w$ is arbitrary, it follows that $u,v$ are parallel to each other. Since $u$ and $v$ are (left or right) singular vectors, in turn we must have $u=\pm v$. Thus $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable.

Now suppose $v$ and $w$ are two linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively. Then
\begin{align*}
&A(vw^T - wv^T)A^T = vw^T - wv^T\\
\Rightarrow&\lambda\mu (vw^T - wv^T) = vw^T - wv^T.
\end{align*}
Therefore $\lambda\mu=1$ for any two eigenvalues $\lambda,\,\mu$ of $A$. Hence $A=\pm I$.